# Angular rxjs conditional get query

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

My json file contains several arrays, like below :

```json
{
    A[]
    B[]
    C[]
    ...
}
```

My query looks like this  :

```js
myFunction():void{
this.apiService.getData()
.pipe(
  map((response: any) => response.A), // to access to the 'A' array
  take(1)
  )
.subscribe((records: MyType[]) => {
  this.records = records
});
}
```

This query is the same for each array. Just need to change 'A' by the right array name (B, C).

I don't know if it's possible but what I need is just pass a variable to the function and have a 'switch case' to redirect to the right table.

I watched to switchMap operator but it seems not to be the right solution.

Any suggestion is hepfull

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the problem right, it looks you may go with something like this

```
myFunction(arrayName: string):void{
  this.apiService.getData()
  .pipe(
    map((response: any) => response[arrayName]),
    // you do not need take(1) if the apiService wraps the http client
    // http client notifies one value and then completes immediately after
    )
  .subscribe((records: MyType[]) => {
    this.records = records
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise (take(1)). 
Yes that's it. Just specify the name of the array.

Comment: The used to be a **pluck** operator, but it's deprecated, so this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems to work but I'm not sure it's the best one.

```js
myFunction(prov: string): void{
    this.jsonService.getData()
      .pipe(
        map((response: any) => 
                prov === "A" ? response.A 
              : prov === "B" ? response.B 
              : prov === "C" ? response.C 
              : ...
              : response.Z
          )
        )
        .subscribe((record: any) =>
        this.records = records
      )
   }
```

But the solution of Picci is easiest !